# OpenLayers 6.x: Incorrect Static Image Location On Map -- React NextJS

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers, radar, react

VvI have been searching across the interwebs to find an answer to my problem that was answered a decade ago for a much older version of OpenLayers. I am trying to overlay a NWS Radar mosaic on top of an OSM map.

There have been plenty of complications upon the way because of the platforms I am using (mainly NextJS). I am pretty sure I resolved all the issues, but the alignment of my image still does not work.

Below is my constructor from the component that will manage the running of the OpenLayer app:

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { center: [-10720000, 4550000], zoom: 4 };
        //IMPORTANT: Next.js doesn't work well with openLayer
        //SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56508322/openlayers-compilation-error-with-react-next
        const KML = require("ol/format/KML").default;
        const Map = require("ol/Map").default;
        const OSM = require("ol/source/OSM").default;
        const TileLayer = require("ol/layer/Tile").default;
        //const VectorSource = require("ol/source/Vector").default;
        //const VectorLayer = require("ol/layer/Vector").default;
        const ImageLayer = require("ol/layer/Image").default;
        const Static = require("ol/source/ImageStatic").default;
        const View = require("ol/View").default;
        const Projection = require("ol/proj/Projection").default;
        const TransformExtent = require("ol/proj");
        //Establish the vector layer for the KML
        //SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32135596/open-layers-2-12-and-3-kml-groundoverlay-and-screenoverlay-support
        //SO: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8981/openlayers-all-image-layers-are-out-of-place-on-google-maps-v3-and-osm-base-lay/9014
        //SO: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13249/reprojecting-base-layers-in-openlayers
        //SO: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/126979/i-cant-get-my-openlayers-radar-overlay-to-display-correctly
        //var extent = [-14206635.22, 2469859.05, -7404742.97, 6516996.45]; // [minx,miny,maxx,maxy]
        //const extent = [-14206593.415,2205071.940,-7394741.764,6517585.728];
        const extentBounds = [-14206635.218164166, 2469859.049484826, -7404742.9730659835, 6516996.454856468]; // [minx,miny,maxx,maxy]
        const extent = new TransformExtent.transformExtent(extentBounds, 'EPSG:900913', 'EPSG:3857');
        console.log(extent);
        const projection = new Projection({code: 'EPSG:3857', extent:extent});
        const radarLayer = new ImageLayer({
            source: new Static({
              url: 'https://cdn.wxyard.com/splashradar.png',
              projection: projection,
              imageExtent: extent,
              imageSize: [3400,1600]
            }),
          });
        
        console.log(radarLayer);
        this.olmap = new Map({
            target: null, //Needs to be null for app to initially load
            layers: [new TileLayer({source: new OSM()}), radarLayer],
            view: new View({
                center: this.state.center,
                zoom: this.state.zoom
            })
        });
        this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this);
        this.updateMap = this.updateMap.bind(this);
        this.shouldComponentUpdate = this.shouldComponentUpdate.bind(this);
    }
```

I went and tried to use the bounds from this exchange link: [Source Of Transformed Bounds](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8981/openlayers-all-image-layers-are-out-of-place-on-google-maps-v3-and-osm-base-lay/9014) without using `transformExtent` and sticking to `EPSG:3857` and the image still didn't line up.

From what I can tell by looking at the code, `transformExtent` should work the same as the old bounding processes that I have commented out in the snippet.

Below is a reference to what the image looks like on the map vs an actual radar image of where the reflectivity should be.

Can you provide any ideas or guidance?

OSM Reference

[image]

Reality

[image]

Comment: To get https://cdn.wxyard.com/splashradar.png to produce output matching https://www.weather.gov/gis/ it needs to be specified as EPSG:4326  https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-bassi-tt1uv?file=/main.js

Comment: Hi there @mike. Your code sandbox link definitely shows it working right. Everything I had looked at in the past was hounding on the `EPSG:3857`. I will modify my changes this evening. Thanks for your help! Can you make this an answer so I can give you credit plz? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Mike. I was wondering if you knew the bounds for the Ridge 2 radar data? I went to use it and things don't line up again. I think it's a bounds issue.